# Change of energy of a shortening simple pendulum (Ehrenfest Pendulum)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism

I've been going through Lanczos' *Variational Principles of Mechanics* and have been struggling with a problem that seemed pretty straightforward:

A simple pendulum hangs from a fixed pulley. The pendulum's length shortens with uniform velocity. Show the change of the total energy from position $\theta = 0$ to the next position $\theta = 0$ (where $\theta$ is the angle relative to the axis of suspension) is given by:

$\Delta E = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Delta l}{l} E$

Where $E$ is the energy constant of the undisturbed oscillations.

So we have

$T = \frac{m}{2}(\dot l^2 + l^2 \dot \theta^2)$

$V = m g l (1 - \cos(\theta)) \approx mgl\frac{\theta^2}{2}$

$L = T - V = \frac{m}{2}(\dot l^2 + l^2 \dot \theta^2) - mgl\frac{\theta^2}{2}$

And I believe our "undisturbed" $E = \frac{m}{2}l^2 \dot \theta^2$ for position $\theta = 0$, which means we want $\Delta E = -\frac{m}{4}l \Delta l \dot \theta^2$

For a rheonomic condition, the change in energy of a system is given by

$\Delta E = - \int^{t_2}_{t_1} \frac{\partial L}{\partial t} dt$

This part is where I'm fuzzy, but it seems that given the form of our Lagrangian, we should be able to rephrase that as

$\Delta E = -[L]^{t_2}_{t_1} = -\frac{m}{2}[(\dot l^2 + l^2 \dot \theta^2) - gl\theta^2]^{t_2}_{t_1}$

And from our starting conditions the terms in $\dot l$ and $\theta$ should drop out, so

$\Delta E = -\frac{m}{2}(l(t_2)^2 - l(t_1)^2)\dot \theta^2$

Expanding the difference of two squares:

$\Delta E = -\frac{m}{2}(l(t_2) + l(t_1))(l(t_2) - l(t_1))\dot \theta^2 \approx -\frac{m}{2}(2 l)\Delta l\dot \theta^2 = - m l \Delta l \dot \theta^2$

Which aggravatingly puts me off by a factor of 4. Any insight would be appreciated.